# How to let nginx simply pass a request to a forwarding proxy server?

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, forwarding

'm behind my corporate forwarding proxy.

When I test my application locally, for some requests, I want to configure nginx to proxy_pass those requests to some external domain servers.

below is my configuration, while this doesn't work. I'm always getting 502 bad gateway error. so I'm thinking is it due to I'm behind a corporate proxy? How can I configure nginx simply pass the request to the forwarding proxy?

```
location ~* ^/proxy/(.*) {
    proxy_pass http://services.odata.org/$1$is_args$args;
}
```

What I want to achieve is:
[image]

Comment: What is in the log on the other end?

Comment: @Anatoly  what you mean for "the other end"?